# Stacked bar charts with differing x axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to create a stacked barchart.

I have multiple arrays to plot but will simplify it to 2 for the sake of this questions.

```
rates = [4, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5]
counts = [12, 17, 22, 9, 12, 18]

rates1 = [4.3, 4.4]
counts1 = [24, 17]
```

I want to plot a barchart for rates against counts, with the rates1 bar stacked above it.

I am getting an error due to the mismatched size of the arrays.

I believe I need to fill in where the rates are "missing", eg. 4.1, with a zero value. But don't want to hardcode this. I also can't just pad the end of the list with zeroes as then the counts won't align with the correct rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dictionaries for the arrays and then use a dict comprehension to pad the missing data points:

```
data = dict(zip(rates, counts)
data
>>> {4: 12, 4.1: 17, 4.2: 22, 4.3: 9, 4.4: 12, 4.5: 18}
data1 = dict(zip(rates1, counts1)
data1
>>> {4.3: 24, 4.4: 17}
data1 = {k: data1[k] if k in data1 else 0 for k in data}
data1
>>> {4: 0, 4.1: 0, 4.2: 0, 4.3: 24, 4.4: 17, 4.5: 0}
```

To access the data, you can use the `dict.keys()` (for the rates) and the `dict.values()` (for the counts) methods.

**Edit:**
As commented by colidyre, you don't need the `.keys()` method when iterating over dictionaries. So I removed it from my answer.

Comment: FWIW: You don't necessarily need `.keys()` method since iteration over dictionary already means iteration over dictionary keys. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60981394/2648551.