# Python function to convert JSON to CSV not saving data properly

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to build a function in Python to transform a specififc json file to csv, but it is not working properly, it compiles but do not save data from the file properly, just anme of the columns and word "data" as separate letters in first 4 columns like this :

```
id,uuid,position,created_at,created_meta,updated_at,updated_meta,meta,indicator,indicator_description,geo_type,geo_name,geo_id,variable,time_period,time_period_label,value,footnote
d,a,t,a
```

How can i make this code work properly ?

I tried multiple solutions, but the closest i got is:

```
import json
import csv

# Open the JSON file and load the data
with open('main_dataset copy.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Create a CSV file and write the headers
with open('suicide_deaths.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(
        ['id', 'uuid', 'position', 'created_at', 'created_meta', 'updated_at', 'updated_meta', 'meta', 'indicator',
         'indicator_description', 'geo_type', 'geo_name', 'geo_id', 'variable', 'time_period', 'time_period_label',
         'value', 'footnote'])

    # Write each row of data to the CSV file
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

And here is how more or less the json file looks:

```
{
  "data" : [ [ "row-sj5k-g243-v6cb", "00000000-0000-0000-ED82-9AA08DFD0A9A", 0, 1623083971, null, 1623083971, null, "{ }", "Death rates for suicide", "Deaths per 100,000 resident population, age-adjusted", "1", "Total", "0", "All persons", "0", "1950", "1", "All ages", "0", "13.2", null ]
, [ "row-ejmi~wx6s-9cxn", "00000000-0000-0000-6815-4FD0CEFCA3F6", 0, 1623083971, null, 1623083971, null, "{ }", "Death rates for suicide", "Deaths per 100,000 resident population, age-adjusted", "1", "Total", "0", "All persons", "0", "1960", "2", "All ages", "0", "12.5", null ]
, [ "row-db2i-62a7_cm7e", "00000000-0000-0000-3CBC-D99BAFDC625B", 0, 1623083971, null, 1623083971, null, "{ }", "Death rates for suicide", "Deaths per 100,000 resident population, age-adjusted", "1", "Total", "0", "All persons", "0", "1970", "3", "All ages", "0", "13.1", null ]
, [ "row-usyq~7vsy~ag46", "00000000-0000-0000-DAE8-3BAD17B11C1C", 0, 1623083971, null, 1623083971, null, "{ }", "Death rates for suicide", "Deaths per 100,000 resident population, age-adjusted", "1", "Total", "0", "All persons", "0", "1980", "4", "All ages", "0", "12.2", null ]
,
```

Comment: You need to loop over the list: `for row in data['data']:` You're looping over the keys of the dictionary, treating each key as a row.

Comment: Like this ?  ``  # Write each row of data to the CSV file
    for row in data['data']:
        writer.writerow(row)

Comment: yes, like that.

Comment: @colidyre Looked into what? Are you saying it feels odd to form an answer the mirrors a comment?  Happens all the time :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you were confused about the variable name `data`. The `data` variable is the complete json which gives you the dictionary. Iterating over a dictionary means iterating over the keys of a dictionary, similar to `dict.keys()` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60981394/2648551) for more details).

So you simply have to iterate over the values of the `data` attribute like this:

```
for row in data['data']:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

and you will receive your data.

I would recommend to rename the `data` attribute in the json file or even better to rename the `data` variable to something like `content`.

```
with open('main_dataset copy.json') as f:
    content = json.load(f)
```

Then it is a bit clearer, that 'data' of the dictionary has to be addressed:

```
...
for row in content['data']:
    writer.writerow(row)
```